# How to avoid redundant code in designing inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say I have a Base class called `Car` and it has 3 derived  classes say `Ford`, `Honda` and  `Audi`.

The issue is, all three derived classes have exactly same code but minor difference in calling member functions of  their respective engines (these engines have separate class).

For example, `Ford` class calls code which is exactly same as other two  classes  but do call something like `ford_engine-> start()`,  `ford_engine->clean()` etc.

```
//ly  honda  calls   honda_engine->start()   honda_engine->clean();

//ly  Audi calls audi_engine->start()  audi->clean();
```

Now here the issue is, it has redundant code in all three places with minute difference. How can I have code at one place, most  probably in base class and all derived classes use same code?

Comment: composition over inheritance, make an abstract engine class that the now concrete car object has a reference to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to add a read only protected member variable (i.e. a protected property) engine to your superclass. Then, redefine the accessor in the subclasses to return the proper engine instance. Your code become `this->getEngine()->start()` and so on.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, **Ford**, **Honda** and **Audi** probably should *not* be classes derived from **Car**. Derivation should reflect differences in *behavior* on an abstract level.

In this case, it probably makes more sense to simply have a `Car` object with a field identifying the manufacturer. The `Car` owns an engine--but in a typical case, you don't need a different class for each brand of engine either; at an abstract level, the brand is generally irrelevant.

As such, you can have something like:

```
class Car {
    class Engine {
        enum { diesel, piston, rotor, electric, hybrid } type;

        int HP;
        int torque;
        int max_rpm;

        bool running;

        void start() { running = true; }
        void stop() { running = false; }
        // ...
    } engine;

    std::string brand;
    std::string model;
};
```

In a few cases you honestly *need* to model an engine at a level of detail where things like firing order really matter, and you'll need much more detail than this. It should still be at a behavioral level though. If you had a `Ford_motor` vs. `Honda_motor` the brand should still really be a short-hand for behavioral differences. You really want to maintain the most abstract view you can though, so you usually want to model an engine (car, etc.) in terms of behavior. The difference between a Ford and a Honda motor should be things like one has higher torque and the other higher red-line than the other; these differences can be modeled quite easily by supplying suitable parameters when instantiating the object. If Ford and Honda were to produce engines with identical characteristics (not just power, but power curves, etc.) then the difference in brand is irrelevant to your modeling.

Oh, and no you should *not* have a `getEngine` as a member of a `Car`. A car is a car. It *has* an engine. If you provide a `getEngine` at all, it should be a member of `AutoPartsStore` or something on that order (but unless you're dealing with buying and selling engines, you probably shouldn't have such a thing at all).

When a person starts their car, the don't *get* the engine and start the engine. They start the car and after they do so (successfully), the car is running. Forcing a client to use a `getEngine` and start the engine is both crappy from a coding viewpoint *and* from a modeling viewpoint--starting my car does *more* than just start the engine. It also controls things like some of the lights, the radio, heating/air conditioning, and so on. One of the basic points of object-oriented programming is to *protect* client code from dealing with all these internal details, *not* to force them to deal with the details *and* use crappy `getXxx()` syntax to do it!